# Prove that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z},x + 3y$ is a multiple of $7$ iff $3x + 2y$ is a multiple of $7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling with this problem, could someone point me in the right direction?

Prove that for all $x$ and $y$ in set $\mathbb{Z}$, $x+3y$  is a multiple of $7$ iff $(3x + 2y)$ is a multiple of $7$

I don't really want the answer just some direction on how to work through this. Thanks.

Comment: I think I did not understand the question. What should we prove is a multiple of $7\forall x,y\in Z$?

Comment: its a question i got in my college workbook i can't quite grasp
your notation is correct 7∀x,y∈Z 
for all x and y in set Z (which i assume is integers) prove that x + 3y is a multiple of 7 if and only if 3x + 2y is also a multiple of 7

Comment: Don't you think there should be *something* between "...in the set $\mathbb{Z}$" and "is a multiple of $7$..." ? *Something* that we would prove?

Comment: I think you missed you $x+3y$ is a multiple of $7$ in your original question. You should edit to add that.

Comment: oh :p thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ ( x+3y) + 2(3x+2y) = 7(x+y)$$

Thus $(x+3y)$ is a multiple of $7$ iff $2(3x+2y)$ is a multiple of $7$

Since $2$ and $7$ are relatively prime, the above statement is equivalent to $(x+3y)$ is a multiple of $7$ iff $(3x+2y)$ is a multiple of $7$

Comment: i realised what i had to do on your first comment :p but thanks that helped a lot

Comment: @Wyrmbeard Thanks for  your understanding and attention.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to eliminate one of the variables.

$$3x+2y-3(x+3y)=-7y$$

So, $7|(3x+2y)\iff7|3(x+3y)$

But $7\nmid 3,7|3(x+3y)\implies7|(x+3y)$

Alternatively, $$3(3x+2y)-2(x+3y)=7x$$

So, $7|3(3x+2y)\iff7|2(x+3y)$

But $7\nmid 3,7\nmid2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array} {rrll}
& 0 \equiv & x + 3y \\
\iff & 0 \equiv & 3(x + 3y) \\
\iff & 0 \equiv & 3x + 2y & \pmod 7
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove: $$7\mid x + 3y \iff 7\mid 3x + 2y$$

---

Say $7\mid x+3y $ then $x+3y = 7k$ so $x= 7k-3y$, so we have $$3x+2y = 3(7k-3y)+2y =21k-7y = 7(3k-y) \implies 7\mid 3x+2y$$

Say $7\mid 3x+2y$ then $3x+2y = 7l$ so $y = {7l-3x\over 2}$, so we have $$ x+3y = {2x+21l-9x\over 2} = 7{3l-x\over 2} \implies 7\mid 2(x+3y) \implies 7\mid x+3y$$